# Spring Page.getContent giving class cast exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

Because of some need, I have manually did like this in spring data jpa:

```
List<Foo> fooList = repository.findAll();
PageRequest pg = new PageRequest(1, 20);
Page<Foo> pageFoo = new PageImpl<Foo>(fooList, pageRequest, fooList.size());
final List<Foo> iterable = pageFoo.getContent();

for(Foo foo : iterable) {

}
```

In the line of for loop I am getting *class cast exception* saying object can't cast to foo.

Why is like that? But when I do `iterable.size()` its giving the actual count of records in the object.

Please help me to solve this case.

Comment: Mohan Can you provide your tried code in details with full method

Comment: I have updated the snippet. I don't have permission to upload full source code.

Answer (score 0):

It's Pageable not PageRequest for further ref:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageImpl.html

```
List<Foo> fooList = repository.findAll();
Pageable pg = new PageRequest(1, 20); // 
Page<Foo> pageFoo = new PageImpl<Foo>(fooList, pg, fooList.size());
final List<Foo> iterable = pageFoo.getContent();
for(Foo foo : iterable) {
 .....
}
```

Comment: Still I'm getting the Object as the output and same Class Cast Exception.